# Need to retrive a Table<T> from linq

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have a function where I need to retrieve a Table view of my data.
As I need to bind the data to a grid I need the results as a Table.

```
    internal static Table<MyObject> GetUsersData()
    {
        var db = new DataContext();

        var results = from user in db.Results
                      where user.Type == "USERTYPE"
                      select user;


        return results;
    }
```

if I was to get the whole table it works fine as it retrieves the table as a Table.

```
 var results = db.Results;
```

The error I get is

```
Error   6   Cannot implicitly convert type An explicit conversion exists
```

***Is there a way to cast the results into a table?***

Im trying to bind this data to a grid, Im starting to think I should create a View on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your method return: `IQueryable<Result>`

```
internal static IQueryable<Result> GetUsersData()
{
//...your method code
}
```

Comment: ok, just tried it and worked, didnt know datagridview would accept anything else that wasnt a DataTable.